# Using Xamarin to create Android bluetooth terminal to connect to HC-06 module

Tags: android, bluetooth, terminal, xamarin

I'm trying to build a very simple app that would allow me to communicate with a HC-06 chip (simple UART interface)  from Android very similar to BlueTerm or something similar currently on the play store. The standard bluetooth example given by Xamarin would work fine but doesn't connect to the bluetooth module (simply says unable to connect to device). If anyone has any ideas of why it might be doing this and/or how to fix it, it would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

`HC05` work in both `master` and `slave` mode. `HC05` default on slave mode like hc06.

I found in Xamarin blog this link 3 years ago: https://blog.xamarin.com/hello-mr-bond_agent_watch/

This page about some kind of smart watch which create with micro-controller, but you can download a project for android called NetduinoBT_AgentProto that completely contain every thing that you need to connect to Bluetooth SPP (serial port profile).

add `App.cs` class into your project.

and this permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
```

For get list and name of devises:

```
var list = App.Current.BondedBluetoothDeviceNames;
var name  = App.Current.BondedBluetoothDeviceNames[yourIndex];`
```

For connect to device:
    bool connected = App.Current.ConnectToBluetoothDevice(name , out message);

You can establish 'MessageReceived' event for get back your device response :

```
string mYourResult;
...
protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
{
    ...
    App.Current.MessageReceived += (object sender, App.MessageReceivedEventArgs e) => {
        RunOnUiThread( () => {
            mYourResult = e.MessageString;
        });
    };
    ...
}
```

For sending string:
`App.Current.SendStringToBluetoothDevice("Your String");`

in my experiences in some systems that based on Linux core you need add next line in end of your string.some thing like: "\r\n" or "\n" or "\r" or Environment.NewLine

Answer (score 0):

This is an application which I used for testing HC-05 and HC-06 module.

[‌BluetoothTerminal](http://wikisend.com/download/469032/BluetoothTerminal.apk)

That's very simple.
Just connect to your device and send data.
Received data will be shown too.